# Definition of pole of a spherical mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, lenses

what can be a suitable definition to a pole of the spherical mirror. It cant be the geometrical center of a spherical mirror as if a mirror is cut then its pole does not change. moreover if a spherical mirror is cut into two parts then it does not have two poles.

Comment: Man, I'm having the same confusion. My physics teacher is not sure of the answer either.

Answer (score 2):

The point where the principal axis pierces the mirror  is the pole. And this principlal axis can be any normal to the surface. It is what we assume according to our convenience.

Answer (score -1):

It is twice the focus. Focus is the point where llght rays parrallel to principal axis will converge after getting reflected from the mirror.

Comment: i guess that is the definition of the radius of curvature of a spherical mirror